# Android class design - should I reinstantiate dialog classes in my activity each time I want to show them?

Tags: android, class-design

MainActivity:

```
GeneralDialogFragment history_dialog = new GeneralDialogFragment();
public void showHistory(View view) {

    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putString("dialog_type", "history");

    history_dialog.setArguments(bdl);
    history_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
}
```

This code lives inside my activity.

Now, I was wandering whether I should put the definition

```
GeneralDialogFragment history_dialog = new GeneralDialogFragment();
```

inside or outside the showHistory() function?

What's the difference? Am I conserving memory if I put it outside (so It's instantiated only once?)

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you do that is primarily dependent on what the Fragment does. The overhead to create a new Fragment object is miniscule, but can add up depending on how many you need to make.  If a `DialogFragment` is static and pops up every second (why would you do that?!?!), then it would probably be worth keeping it around.  If a `DialogFragment` pops up every minute, then the end user probably won't notice if you're recreating the object every time.

Generally speaking though, Android (Google) recommends doing the lazy-loading approach.  So if you created the object at the beginning of that method and called `show()`, you would lose the reference to it.  There will still be a reference to it in the application's `FragmentManager`, so it will stay in memory. Once you call `dismiss()`, the `Fragment` will be removed and its memory that it is taking up will be garbage collected.  Doing it this way has a slight CPU overhead, but at the gain of minimizing memory usage.

The exception to this would be if there's a lot of resources that need to be allocated for the fragment.  In **that** case, it would be wise to load the resources once then keep them around.  Images for example are better cached because they can take a long time to decode. They don't have to be saved in the Fragment itself, but it would be good for large images to stay in memory and passed to new Fragments as they are being created.

**EDIT:**
Just a side note, if you do decide that the reference needs to be kept, it would be good to have a check to make sure the dialog isn't already shown. The app will currently crash if you call `showHistory()` again if the dialog is currently up because you're calling `setArguments()` on a `Fragment` that is attached to the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how many times you want to call the showHistoryMethod() and also do you need the object history_dialog outside the showHistory() method.

So assuming the object is not needed outside the showHistory() method and it will be only called once during the Activity, or not called at all, then place it inside the showHistory() method.

If you place it outside then the instance of GeneralDialogFragment will live during the lifetime of your main Acitivity. Whereas if it is inside the showHistory method than the GarabageCollector will free the memory, once it is not needed.